# Picturebox disappears with negative Top & Left values

Tags: vb.net

I have a picturebox on a form that users can drag around. It's Top & Left properties are saved so the picturebox appears in the same place when the form is closed & opened again.

It's works fine unless there is a lot of white or blank space in the image and the user pushes the topleft corner far off the form into a negative value, the image won't reappear once it's visible properly is set to false & then true again or the form is closed & reopened. Negative values are usually ok unless the values are greater(technically less than) than -100. I've not yet found the exact limit. I've saw the issue occur around -100 top and -250+ left.

I'm trying to figure out why this is happening. As far as I know the top and left properties are stored as an integer which can hold around -2billion+ so I don't believe that's the problem.

Any ideas?

This is how the picturebox is moved:

```
Private Sub picBox_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles picBox.MouseDown
    off.X = MousePosition.X - sender.Left
    off.Y = MousePosition.Y - sender.Top
End Sub

Private Sub picBox_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles picBox.MouseMove
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        sender.Left = MousePosition.X - off.X
        sender.Top = MousePosition.Y - off.Y
    End If
End Sub
```

This is how the Top & Left properties are saved:

```
Private Sub picBox_LocationChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picBox.LocationChanged
    If globalMode > "" Then
        'If picBox.Top < 0 Then picBox.Top = 0
        'If picBox.Left < 0 Then picBox.Left = 0
        MainForm.overlays.Item(globalMode & "PicLocTop") = picBox.Top
        MainForm.overlays.Item(globalMode & "PicLocLeft") = picBox.Left
    End If
End Sub
```

This is how the picturebox is removed from the form:

```
Private Sub closeContent()
    lblContent.Visible = False
    picBox.Visible = False
    picBox.ImageLocation = ""
    picBox.Top = 12
    picBox.Left = 28
    Me.Height = origH
    Me.Width = origW
    lblContent.Top = 44
    lblContent.Left = 92
End Sub
```

This is how the picturebox reappears:

```
Private Sub openContent(mode As String)
    lblContent.Visible = True
    picBox.Visible = True
    If MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "Image") > "" Then
        picBox.ImageLocation = MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "Image")
    End If
    If Not IsNothing(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "PicLocTop")) Then
        picBox.Top = CInt(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "PicLocTop"))
    End If
    If Not IsNothing(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "PicLocLeft")) Then
        picBox.Left = CInt(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "PicLocLeft"))
    End If
    If Not IsNothing(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "H")) Then
        Me.Height = CInt(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "H"))
    End If
    If Not IsNothing(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "W")) Then
        Me.Width = CInt(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "W"))
    End If
    If Not IsNothing(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "ContentTop")) Then
        lblContent.Top = CInt(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "ContentTop"))
    End If
    If Not IsNothing(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "ContentLeft")) Then
        lblContent.Left = CInt(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "ContentLeft"))
    End If

    If MainForm.overlays.Item("apiBGr") > "" Or MainForm.overlays.Item("apiBGg") > "" Or MainForm.overlays.Item("apiBGb") > "" Then
        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Val(MainForm.overlays.Item("apiBGr")), Val(MainForm.overlays.Item("apiBGg")), Val(MainForm.overlays.Item("apiBGb")))
    End If
    lblContent.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(Val(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "FontR")), Val(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "FontG")), Val(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "FontB")))
    If MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "FontBGr") = "" And MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "FontBGg") = "" And MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "FontBGb") = "" Then
        lblContent.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    Else
        lblContent.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Val(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "FontBGr")), Val(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "FontBGg")), Val(MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "FontBGb")))
    End If
    SetFont(mode)
    If MainForm.overlays.Item(mode & "ImageResize") = "True" Then
        picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    Else
        picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
    End If
    lblContent.Refresh()
    picBox.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: I know. That's not the problem. Saving and reusing the values are working. It's only when those values are negative numbers more than -100 that the issue occurs. Even small negative values between 0 & -90 work just fine.

Comment: does the picturebox disappear or the image in it fail to draw?  also might be worthwhile to know the size of the PBs - -100 and -250 could well mean the control is offscreen

Comment: @Plutonix You gave me the idea of adding a border to the picturebox. I'm also monitoring the visible property of the picturebox to be sure it's toggling correctly and it is indeed set to True when it should be. Strange thing is when I turned the picturebox border on I was able to determine it's the actual picturebox that's not reappearing. I moved the picturebox to the far topleft corner where I could only see the bottom right corner and when reloading the picturebox the border is not appearing as if it didn't load the picturebox at all.

Comment: `.Visible` may not help much.  If a control is behind something or is offscreen it will report `False` simply because the user cannot see it.  Move it onscreen and it will show and the property value will change by itself.

Comment: I didn't know that, but I understand. The picturebox is the only object on the form so it's not hidden behind anything. Also I left enough of the bottom right corner showing so it's not entirely off-screen. Regardless the visible property is always reporting True when it should be. I just can't understand why moving the picturebox off screen is ok unless it's top/left properties exceed a certain value, despite still being able to see the image before closing the form.

Comment: Too little information here. We can only guess. Show some code about how do you move the picbox, change the visibility, the size of it, which values the problem occurs, etc...

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε I added the information you requested. I'm starting to think this is a bug honestly.

Comment: Is *MainForm* a class?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε My main form.

Comment: What is *MainForm.overlays.Item(...)* then?